# How do i differentiate module name from *main exported type* in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, module, namespaces, node-modules

i would like to use my code like this in ts:

// task.ts

```
export type Task = {
  name: string
  description: string
  cost: number
  done: boolean
}


export function increaseCost(task: Task, percent: number) {
  return { ...task, cost: task.cost * (1 + percent / 100) }
}
```

// index.ts

```
import {Task,  increaseCost} from "./task.ts"
 
let task: Task = {...}

Task.increaseCost(task, 15)
Task.anotherFunction(task)
Task.yetAnotherFunction(task)
```

Basically i would like to do Task as a namespace. But **type** Task is interfering.

An option would be:

// task.ts

```
export type Task
```

and then

// index.ts

```
import * as Task from "task.ts"
let task: Task.Task // this seems redundant
```

Another option:

// task.ts

```
export type Type
```

// index.ts

```
import * as Task from "task.ts" 
let task: Task.Type // seems odd/weird
```

How would you approach this? How would you differentiate module/namespace Task from Task type?

Comment: Please use a more descriptive title

Comment: It's not super clear what you want: `Task` is a type, do you *also* have some object called `Task`? Because otherwise the code `Task.increaseCost(task, 15)` doesn't make sense.

Comment: @VLAZ i want to use Task as a namespace (a group of functions related to a Task type). I want to prefix each one of those function with "Task". But of course, Task is already an exported type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `module` or `namespace` keywords, although `module` is not recommended anymore:

```
import { Task } from './task';
let a: Task = { cost: 10, description: '', done: false, name: '' };
console.log(Task.increaseCost(a, 10));
```

```
// task.ts
export type Task = {
  name: string;
  description: string;
  cost: number;
  done: boolean;
};

export namespace Task {
  export function increaseCost(task: Task, percent: number) {
    return { ...task, cost: task.cost * (1 + percent / 100) };
  }
}
```

A online demo is at here [stackblitz type](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-3yrjml?file=index.ts). (Open the console to see the result.)

Comment: thats exactly what i want. could **module** be replaced with **namespace** somehow? provided that **module** is not recommended

Comment: Yes you can. I'll add it to the code. Glad to see it helps.